# How to get query data from redirected url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a card payment that returns a response with a redirect URL. I have to redirect the user after the payment has been initialized.
I am doing that using:

```
...
 window.location.href = response.data.meta.authorization.redirect
```

To have the payment validated on a page I do not have control over.

After validation I have a redirect URL in my request that redirects (browser redirect) the user back to my application with query data that looks like this:

```
http://account.localhost.com/deposit/card?response=%7B"id"%3A1499407,"txRef"%3A"tUhElMQhoC"...,
```

I need the id in that url to verify the payment and subsequently update my database.

How can I do this with Vue?

Comment: Are you using Vue-router?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Yes i am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Vue-router, you can get query params with `this.$route.query`, then to access a specific parameter: `this.$route.query.id`

As the ID is inside a stringified JSON object, you'd have to parse it first: `JSON.parse(this.$route.query.response).id`

So, with a redirect, it makes sense to access the data in the `created` lifecycle hook:

```
created() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.$route.query.response).id);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does this code go in my component after a browser redirect?

Comment: Usually, in the `created` hook

Comment: I am getting ````undefined````

Comment: Sorry, I misread your URL. You'd have to do `JSON.parse(this.$route.query.response).id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to retrieve the json in the `response` parameter, then parse it and get the id from resultant object.

```js
const str = `http://account.localhost.com/depositcard?response=%7B"id"%3A1499407,"txRef"%3A"tUhElMQhoC"%7D`

const json = new URL(str).searchParams.get('response')
const obj = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(obj.id)
```